# Space Complexity for Recursion

Tags: java, algorithm, space-complexity

For a simple program:

```
public class solution{
    public void start(int m, int n){
        for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
            recur(n);
    }

    public void recur(int n){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            recur(n-1);
    }
}
```

Could anyone help me analysis the space complexity? I think it is O(m*n).

Thanks.

Comment: I agree with you.  Because the loop counter `i` in `start()` is independent of the call to `recur(n)`, the code is essentially doing an `O(n)` operation `m` times, which gives `O(m*n)` as you have said.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The call stack will never exceed O(n) many elements, so that's the space complexity. Every branch of the recursion tree will be processed while no other elements that only lie on other branches take up any space, and the tree's depth is O(n), so that's how much space we need.

Comment: In coding interviews, when we talk about space complexity, should we consider heap space, stack space, or both?

Comment: @Sriram I don't know; I would mention those, and ask whether they want this to be included in your analysis, or say whether you think it should be.

Comment: Could the downvoter let me know what's wrong with this answer?